# order highest to lowest and position changes from another arraylist java

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, compare-and-swap

i have two arraylist.,

one is integer array and another one is string array. Here i need to order the integer array values to sort from highest value to lowest value. at this time i need to moving the position from string array also.

For eg :

String Array : [Register & Head of Administration, Web Designing, IT - Software Engineer, Accountant, Network Engineer] 
Int Array :    [4, 2, 2, 6, 2]

But i need a result from above .,

String Array : [Accountant, Register & Head of Administration, IT - Software Engineer, Network Engineer,Web Designing] 
Int Array :    [6, 4, 2, 2, 2]

Need to sort the integer array and also same time changing the string array position and if the same values occurs in integer array , need to order the alphabetical order. How can i do ?

any shortest way is there ?

Comment: The most reasonable way is changing this 2 ArrayList into 1 ArrayList of Objects, where Class will have 2 fields: String name, and int value. Also in this class implements intefrace Comparable basing on value. And then it will be just using Collections.sort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 4, 2, 2, 6, 2 };
String[] strArray = new String[] { "Register & Head of Administration", "Web Designing", "IT - Software Engineer", "Accountant", "Network Engineer" };
int tmp0 = 0;
String tmp1 = "";
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < intArray.length; j++) {

        if (intArray[j] > intArray[i]) {

            // swap in int-Array
            tmp0 = intArray[i];
            intArray[i] = intArray[j];
            intArray[j] = tmp0;

            // swap in string-Array
            tmp1 = strArray[i];
            strArray[i] = strArray[j];
            strArray[j] = tmp1;
        } else if (intArray[j] == intArray[i]) {

            // sorts alphabetically
            if (strArray[j].compareTo(strArray[i]) < 0) {

                tmp1 = strArray[i];
                strArray[i] = strArray[j];
                strArray[j] = tmp1;
            }
        }
    }
}

//output
for (int k = 0; k < intArray.length; k++) {

    System.out.println(strArray[k] + " " + intArray[k]);
}
```

Output:

`Accountant 6
Register & Head of Administration 4
IT - Software Engineer 2
NetworkEngineer 2
Web Designing 2`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> data= new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>();
data.add(new Pair("Register & Head of Administration", 4));
...
data.add(new Pair("Network Engineer", 2));

Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Pair<String, Integer>>() {
@Override
public int compare(final Pair<String, Integer> o1, final Pair<String, Integer> o2) {
    // TODO: implement your logic here, e.g.
    return o1.second.compareTo(o2.second);
}
```

Comment: Not sure, if you spotted, but there are duplicated values (so in your case duplicated keys, so won't be working)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a third class that group all Strings with a Weight.

Create a Comparator to order WeightString then use Stream API to use datas.

```
public class WeightString {
    public String value;
    public int weight;

    public WeightString(String value, int weight) {
        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

public Comparator<WeightString> mWeightStringComparator = 
        (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.weight, o2.weight);


// in code
WeightString[] weightStrings = new WeightString[]{
        new WeightString("a", 12),
        new WeightString("b", 1),
        new WeightString("c", 8),
        new WeightString("d", 4)
};

Stream<WeightString> stringStream = Arrays.stream(weightStrings);
stringStream.sorted(mWeightStringComparator);
WeightString[] orderedWeightStrings = (WeightString[]) stringStream.toArray();

//orderedWeightStrings : [b,d,c,a]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case array small size means use bubble sort(Bubble sort is not a high performance for large array).Sort int Array  based on position you swap string array also like this

```
            int intArray[] = new int[]{4, 2, 2, 6, 2};
            String strArray[]=new String[]{Accountant, Register & Head of Administration, IT - Software Engineer, Network Engineer,Web Designing}
            int n = intArray.length;
            int temp = 0,temp1=0;               
            for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                    for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){                               
                            if(intArray[j-1] < intArray[j]){                                        
                                    temp = intArray[j-1];
                                    temp1=strArray[j-1];
                                    intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                                    strArray[j-1] = strArray[j];
                                    intArray[j] = temp;
                                    strArray[j] = temp1;
                            }                               
                    }
            }
```

Comment: it will be working, but: 1. you don't know the number of items in Arrays, so bubble sort might be not the best, 2nd - why write so much code, when things can be done nicer

Comment: In your case array small size means use bubble sort(Bubble sort is not a high performance for large array)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

This would be structure of your data

```
class DataModel{
  int priority;
  String priorityName;
  DataModel(int priority,String priorityName){
       this.priority = priority; 
       this.priorityName = priorityName;
   }
}
```

Now make a Arraylist of this class `dataArrayList<DataModel>`

Use a Method to sort your int array with priorities

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
   for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){

            if(intArray[j-1] < intArray[j]){

             //add the data of your largest int number in your int Array and use its position to get the data of your String array. 
             dataArrayList.add(new DataModel(your_lagest_int, your_department)); 

        }
    }
}
```

You should get a Sorted Arraylist with all your Data in it.